# Can `if constexpr` be used to declare variables with different types and init-expr

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, if-constexpr

For example:

```
void foo()
{
    if constexpr (...)
        int x = 5;
    else
        double x = 10.0;
    bar(x); // calls different overloads of bar with different values
}
```

It's common case in D lang, but I didn't found info about C++17.

Of course, it is possible to use something like

```
std::conditional<..., int, double>::type x;
```

but only in elementary cases. Even different initializators (as above) creates big problem.

Comment: No it's not possible because of the scoping. Instead call the function inside the `if` or `else`. There might be other solutions as well, but without knowing exactly what problem this is supposed to solve, the use-case for this, it's not really possible to say more at this time.

Comment: Neither of your variables exist upon the point of the call to `bar()`. Your question is just ill-posed and has nothing to do with `constexpr`.

Comment: "call the function inside" - that means duplication of all code and potentially comb explosion with several if expressions. In D static if branches are unscoped. And you still can add extra {} if really want a scope.

Comment: @aaalex88:  overload resolution cannot happen dynamically; the function selected for `bar(x)` must be known at compile time.

Comment: @AndyG it doesn't: `if` is constexpr, so type of `x` is known at compile-time

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no way this code could work. The problem is that `x` is out of scope when you are calling `bar`. But there is a workaround:

```
constexpr auto t = []() -> auto {
  if constexpr(/* condition */) return 1;
  else return 2.9;
}();

bar(t);
```

To explain a little bit, it uses instantly invoked lambda expression along with auto return type deduction. Therefore we are giving t value in place and it does not get out of the scope.

Of course, it wouldn't work if the if statement couldn't have been evaluated at compile time. And if you want to do some runtime operations inside of this lambda you cannot have t as constexpr, but it will still work.

Comment: Thanks to Dev Null who has corrected some syntax errors in my code. Sorry for them, it was written in a bit careless manner just to get an idea.

Comment: Yes, it would be really helpful in many cases. Am I correct that it is possible to make `auto t = [&]() -> auto { .../*some code, depend on runtime function params, but still with constexpr if statement*/... }`?

Comment: @aaalex No. I have tested it. It cannot depend on runtime params at all. If it does, compiler will complain that it cannot evaluate constexpr if, or if you remove constexpr, it won't be able to evaluate auto. So no runtime conditions in this case.

If you make t const instead of constexpr, it can calculate value at runtime, but return type has to be clear at compile time.

Comment: @aaalex88 You could absolutely do something like `[](int x) -> auto { if constexpr(/* condition */) return sqrt(x); else return x; }(someRuntimeInt)`; basically, the part in `/* condition */` needs to be `constexpr`, whereas the actual code inside the branch can be runtime

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways this won't work.

First, a variable is limited to the scope in which it's declared. Leaving out the braces isn't gonna fool the compiler: `int x = 5` is still in its own scope, and disappears immediately after it appears.

Second, the relaxed grammar rules for `if constexpr` only apply within the `if constexpr`'s body. It would be infeasible to allow the context created in the body to leak out to the surrounding scope, since by definition it may not be well-formed, or consistent between the then/else block. (What if the else-block declared `x` as a typename?)

Bottom line, you'll need to move `bar()` into the if-body, or template `foo()` itself and have the type and value of `x` determined by your `...`.

Comment: "What if the else-block declared x as a typename?" - the program is ill-formed, of course. Already said above: if we have several static conditions, they requires exponential number of branches with the same code, so moving `bar` isn't best solution. Also in D `static if` just doesn't create scope, so it is a failure of language design.

Comment: Don't mistake `constexpr if` for `static if`. The two have entirely different aims: One conditionally enables a block, the other conditionally enables a number of lines of code which are injected into the surrounding block. If you'd like to propose `static if` as a feature for C++, the Working Group can be found at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/ .

Comment: Don't bother. D-style `static if` was proposed first. It went down in flames.

Comment: @aaalex88 D's static if doesn't create scope on purpose. Static if/else is a code generation construct, just like static foreach.