# How to use condition to check if typename T is integer type of float type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am going to write a template to generate a vector of random data. The problem is
`std::uniform_int_distribution` only accepts integer type, and `std::uniform_real_distribution` for float type.  I want to combine both. Here is my code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> generate_vector(size_t N, T lower = T(0), T higher = T(99)) {
    // Specify the engine and distribution. 
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(lower, higher);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution(lower, higher);
    }
    std::mt19937 engine; // Mersenne twister MT19937
    auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
    std::vector<T> vec(N);
    std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), generator);
    return vec;
```

I am confusing how to implement statements within if conditions. Integer type should include:`short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long`. Float type includes `float, double, or long double`.

Any help suggestion?

Comment: `if constexpr` and [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) and [`std::is_floating_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point)

Comment: Thank you Justin, I just tried, and found it is C++ 17 supported.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a pre-C++17 compiler, you can use template specialization to implement the `if`-`else` logic.

```
// Declare a class template
template <bool is_integral, typename T> struct uniform_distribution_selector;

// Specialize for true
template <typename T> struct uniform_distribution_selector<true, T>
{
   using type = typename std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
};

// Specialize for false
template <typename T> struct uniform_distribution_selector<false, T>
{
   using type = typename std::uniform_real_distribution<T>;
};


template<typename T>
std::vector<T> generate_vector(size_t N, T lower = T(0), T higher = T(99))
{
   // Select the appropriate distribution type.
   using uniform_distribution_type = typename uniform_distribution_selector<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type;

   uniform_distribution_type distribution(lower, higher);
   std::mt19937 engine;
   auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
   std::vector<T> vec(N);
   std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), generator);
   return vec;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As Justin points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199813/how-to-use-condition-to-check-if-typename-t-is-integer-type-of-float-type-in-c#comment83380712_48199813) it is simple enough to use an `if constexpr` block in the following way:

```
#include <type_traits>

if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {  // constexpr only necessary on first statement
    ...
} else if (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {  // automatically constexpr
    ...
}
```

This is only available C++17. See the C++ references for more information on compile-time type information:

[`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17)

[`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) (since C++11)

[`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) specifier (since C++11)

[Constant Expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) in general.

Comment: Hi,  if constexpr is C++17 new feature, so there is no way or very difficult to implement this in C++11, is it correct?

Comment: What's the difference between `is_floating_point` and `is_floating_point_v`?

Comment: @Karl: [`is_floating_point_v = is_floating_point<T>::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point#Helper_variable_template). It should be used in combination with `if constexpr`.

Comment: is_integral also returns `true` for `bool`. Possibly not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48200042/3779655), [scoping is another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692986/3779655).

The following code should suit your needs:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>
#include <valarray>

template <class D>
std::valarray<typename D::result_type> generate_valarray(size_t N, D distribution) {
    std::random_device device{};
    std::mt19937 engine{device()}; // Mersenne twister MT19937
    auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
    std::valarray<typename D::result_type> container(N);
    std::generate(std::begin(container), std::end(container), generator);
    return container;
}

template <class T>
std::valarray<T> generate_valarray_uniform(size_t N, const T& lower = std::numeric_limits<T>::min(), const T& higher = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
        return generate_valarray( N, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>(lower, higher) );
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {
        return generate_valarray( N, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>(lower, higher) );
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto f = generate_valarray_uniform(1, 0., 10.)[0];
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
}
```