# C++ constexpr conditional initialization

Tags: c++, constexpr

Is there any `constexpr` way to do something like this:

```cpp
constexpr auto var = constexpr(CONST_EXPRESSION) ? A : B;
```

In this example, `CONST_EXPRESSION` is a fairly complex template calculation, as are `A` and `B`. They might not evaluate to exactly the same type but will both have a flavor of `std::string`, e.g., have a `c_str()` method.

Another requirement is that if `CONST_EXPRESSION` is false, `A` may not compile, so the compiler should skip it. (And if it true, `B` may not compile.)

I tried the above and my compiler did not like it. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

I tried a lambda, but it croaks on Microsoft C++ (not on XCode). Here is a more fleshed out version, showing some of my actual code. (This example simply returns an unsigned int, but other use cases would return the complicated types I mentioned above):

```cpp
   for_each_unordered(members, [&](auto member)
   {
      constexpr auto minVersion = [member]() -> auto
      {
         if constexpr(refl::descriptor::has_attribute<min_version>(member))
            return refl::util::get<min_version>(member.attributes).version;
         else
            return 0;
      }();
...
```

`for_each_unordered` is a `constexpr` loop function provided by [`refl-cpp`](https://veselink1.github.io/refl-cpp/md__r_e_a_d_m_e.html).

Microsoft's compiler complains that the variable `member` is outside of scope inside the (nested) lambda and therefore the statement is not `constexpr`. I have tried capturing by-ref, by-val, as a function parameter, and also passing the test in as a bool parameter. No amount of fiddling gets around the issue. It appears to be a bug in the compiler.

Any workaround is going to be more trouble than it's worth. I was hoping there might be `constexpr` equivalent syntax for the `(condition) ? x : y` pattern, perhaps in the stl.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692665/can-if-constexpr-be-used-to-declare-variables-with-different-types-and-init-ex#45692986 help?

Comment: What do you mean by "flavor?" Do you want `var` to always be `std::string` or should its type depend on whether `A` or `B` was evaluated?

Comment: I thought of a lambda, and I didn't know about `-> auto`, which might allow it to work. I am using `refl-cpp`, and I'm already one lambda level deep in this code. The last time I tried to nest to another lambda level, the Microsoft compiler failed to send through the captures I needed. I suppose I should try it again.

Comment: Its type depends on whether `A` or `B` was evaluated, but either way it has some string-like properties.

Comment: You could try putting A or B in functions (including lambdas). If lambdas are broken in your compiler, write out the structs - lambdas are just abbreviated forms of instances of structs/classes. You could also write a function with `if constexpr` in it